# Input Validation Algorithm - Date and Odometer

Tags: java

I'm having a problem making an efficient algorithm that validates my date and odometer input within a given sorted data set. I'm trying to implement a gas mileage tracking program. The sorted data has a date with corresponding odometer value.

Sample Data Set:

```
  Date        Odometer     Index
2021-2-14      156830        0
2021-2-5       156572        1
2021-2-4       156255        2
```

Index 0 being the top and recent data entry.

Sample Input:

```
Date: 2021-2-15
Odometer: 157000
```

I have to determine which position/order the inputted date belongs inside my data set. Since the user date input is greater than my top/recent date I know this belongs to the very top. Then I compare the odometer from that data to my input. If user odometer input is greater than data odometer then it is valid. If its less than then its invalid.

Another Sample Input:

```
Date: 2021-2-14
Odometer: 156255
```

Its okay if the user date input has the same date given in the data set. However, odometer cannot be less than the previously recorded at 156572 on 2021-2-5. So its invalid.

Here is my test input validation algorithm so far:

```
public static Date[] dates = new Date[3];
public static int[] odometer = new int[3];

public static void main(String[] args)
{
        dates[0] = new Date(2021,2,14);
        dates[1] = new Date(2021,2,5);
        dates[2] = new Date(2021,2,4);

        odometer[0] = 156830;
        odometer[1] = 156572;
        odometer[2] = 156255;
        
        //Inputs
        Date inputDate = new Date(2021,2,14);
        int inputOdo = 156255;
        
        if(!hasDuplicate(inputDate, inputOdo))//Checks for duplicate
        {
            int index = -1;
            for(int i=0; i<dates.length; i++)
            {
                if(inputDate.compareTo(dates[i]) >= 0)
                {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(index == 0)
            {
                if(inputOdo <= odometer[index] && inputDate.compareTo(dates[index]) > 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Mileage cannot be less than "
                        + "your previously recorded fill-up at\n"+odometer[index]+" miles on "+dates[index].toString()+".\n");
                }
            }else{

                    if(index > 0)
                    {
                        int top = index-1;
                        int bottom = index;
                        if(inputOdo >= odometer[top])
                        {
                             System.out.println("Mileage cannot be higher than "
                            + "your previously recorded fill-up at\n"+odometer[top]+" miles on "+dates[top].toString()+".\n");
                        }else{
                            if(inputOdo <= odometer[bottom] && bottom != dates.length-1 && !inputDate.equals(dates[bottom]))
                            {
                                System.out.println("Mileage cannot be less than "
                            + "your previously recorded fill-up at\n"+odometer[bottom]+" miles on "+dates[bottom].toString()+".\n");
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        int bottom = dates.length-1;
                        if(inputOdo >= odometer[bottom])
                        {
                             System.out.println("Mileage cannot be higher than "
                            + "your previously recorded fill-up at\n"+odometer[bottom]+" miles on "+dates[bottom].toString()+".\n");
                        }
                    }

            }
            System.out.println("Gas has been added!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Another fill-up with this date and mileage already exist.");
        }
```

hasDuplicate method:

```
 //Checks for duplicate
    public static boolean hasDuplicate(Date date, int odo)
    {
        boolean duplicate = false; //Initialize duplicate variable

        //Checks if date and mileage exist already
        for(int i=0; i<dates.length; i++)
        {
            if(date.equals(dates[i]) && odo == odometer[i]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return duplicate;
    }
```

I hope someone can understand what I am trying to achieve here. Any help and idea will be great! I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Some changes which you may do-

1. Instead of having different array of data and odometer, use an object which implements Comparable interface

   ```
    class MileageData implements Comparable<MileageData> {
            LocalDate date;
            int odometer;

            public MileageData(LocalDate date, int odometer) {
                this.date = date;
                this.odometer = odometer;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
                MileageData anotherData = (MileageData)obj;
                return anotherData.date.equals(this.date) && anotherData.odometer == this.odometer;
            }

            @Override
            public int hashCode(){
                int hash = 7;
                hash = 31 * hash + this.date.hashCode();
                hash = 31 * hash + this.odometer;
                return hash;
            }

            @Override
            public int compareTo(final MileageData o) {
                if (o.date.isBefore(this.date)) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (o.date.isAfter(this.date)) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            @Override
            public String toString(){
                return this.date.toString()+" "+this.odometer;
            }
        }
   ```
2. Storing `MileageData` in `Treeset` which will sort data in the order given in `compareTo` method of `MileageData`.

   ```
    Set<MileageData> data = new TreeSet<>();
    data.add(new MileageData(LocalDate.of(2021,2,14),156830));
    data.add(new MileageData(LocalDate.of(2021,2,4),156255));
    data.add(new MileageData(LocalDate.of(2021,2,4),156255));
    data.add(new MileageData(LocalDate.of(2021,2,5),156572));
   ```

As `Treeset` will not store duplicate data, you don't need separate check for duplicates. Above set will return only three objects instead of four.

Comment: Half way done! Now the plausibility check …

Comment: Thank you for answering. However, not quite I want to achieve here. I'm asking to help for the algorithm for my input validation.

Comment: @aldrich19 If you use objects which support ordering and avoids duplicity like I answered above in your validation algorithm, it may simplify validations you are doing.

Comment: But I also want to compare the odometer and make sure it is in order as well. So I have to compare the date first to determine the correct position then compare odometer to check if its in the right order too.